# Accessing the index or a row in a matrix/ list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

Without using numpy, my question is related to the for loop in Python, as it doesn't have `for i=0, i++ ...`

only
`for i in list`

I need

```
for i in list 
  # print(i.index)
  # i.index being 0 at the first element of the list and
  # ordered to len(list)-1 at the last element
```

There is something I am missing :

```
mat=[[1,0,1],
     [1,1,1],
     [1,0,1]]
 
dict1= []
dict2= []
n=len(mat[0])
for row in mat :
    for j in range(n):           
        if row[j]==0: 
            dict1.append(mat.index(row))
            dict2.append(j)
print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

output should be [0,2] and [1,1] but instead I am getting

```
[0,0] 
[0,1]
```

How do we explain this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is `for i,v in enumerate(my_list): print(i, v)`. The `i` value goes from `0` to `len(my_list) - 1`. The function`enumerate` has keyword argument `start` that allow to specify where `i` starts (as above this defaults to `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.index()`

```
l=[1,2,3]
for i in l:
    print(i,l.index(i))

1 0
2 1
3 2
```

Comment: .. What if `l = [1, 2, 1]`

Comment: is this behavior standard in python? never at all the indices get mixed, say after altering the list?

Comment: @ssp , index() return just the first occurrence, so it is basically useless here

Comment: This turns the simple loop into a nested for loop O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Using .index() is okay, as long as the list does not have double entries, because index returns the index of the first occurrence of an item.

The for loop can iterate over an index *i* in some range as follows:

```
l=[1,2,3,5,6,7,3,1,89,2,77]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    print(l[i], i)
```